# In R, how can I check if two variable names reference the same underlying object?

Tags: r

For example:

```
A <- 1:10
B <- A
```

Both A and B reference the same underlying vector.

Before I plow off and implement something in C... 
Is there a function in R which can test whether two variables reference the same underlying object?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know if they refer to the same underlying object from R code?

Comment: I'm tallying memory usage, and don't want to count the same allocations more than once. Doing it at the R level probably won't be very accurate, but it should give a reasonable ballpark.

Comment: The OP has a valid question, and `identical` doesn't cut it.  Just because two things are identical doesn't mean that lazy evaluation isn't occurring.  One could create a list of 1000 items that consume only marginally more space than 1 item; or create 1000 items separately that do consume 1000x as much space as one item.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `.Internal` `inspect` function:

```
A <- 1:10
B <- A
.Internal(inspect(A))
# @27c0cc8 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
.Internal(inspect(B))  # same
# @27c0cc8 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
B[1] <- 21
.Internal(inspect(B))  # different
# @25a7528 14 REALSXP g0c6 [NAM(1)] (len=10, tl=150994944) 21,2,3,4,5,...
```

Simon Urbanek has written a simple package with similar functionality.  It's called... wait for it... [inspect](http://www.rforge.net/inspect/index.html).  You can get it from [R-forge.net](http://www.rforge.net/) by running:

```
install.packages('inspect',repos='http://www.rforge.net/')
```

UPDATE: A word of warning:

I recommend you use Simon's package because I'm not going to recommend you call `.Internal`.  It certainly isn't intended to be used interactively and it may very well be possible to crash your R session by using it carelessly.

Comment: Oooooooh, I just love what shows up for ?.Internal: `Only true R wizards should even consider using this function, and only R developers can add to the list of internal functions.`  This sentence is rich.  :)  (+1 when I can vote in a bit.)

Comment: Absolutely Fantastic! Thanks, just what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Iterator: I like to pretend to be a wizard.  I have a hat and everything.  I also run with scissors.

Comment: @Joshua: When you get a chance, can you take a look @ [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327521/reference-for-r-wizards).  I want to know where the R wizards publish their secrets.  :)

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: Magic scissors?

Comment: Btw, Simon Urbanek mentioned the package is essentially what's in R, in the comments following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168732/805808).

Comment: Yes, I have ported my `inspect` implementation to core R, and I'm essentially just maintaining the R version of it. Since `inspect` seems to be still used I may re-map it to use the internal version, but you can safely use `.Internal(inspect(x))`. FWIW there is also `R_inspect` at C level (useful in `gdb`).

Answer (score 17):

You can get at this via `tracemem`: if these are pointing to the same memory location, they are the same memory objects.

```
> a = 1:10
> b = a
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x00000000083885e8"
> tracemem(b)
[1] "<0x00000000083885e8"
> b = 1:10
> tracemem(b)
[1] "<0x00000000082691d0"
>
```

As for why it is very useful to know if they are the same objects: if they are pointing to the same object and there's a delayed evaluation / lazy evaluation / promise then if one object changes, calculations will be suspended while a new block of memory is assigned.  In some contexts the delay can be substantial.  If there are large objects, then the wait is long while a big block of memory is allocated and copied.  Other times it could just be a death by a thousand cuts: lots of little perturbations and delays here and there.

Update (Incorporating Joshua's comment): Be sure to use `untracemem()`, lest you get lots of output.  You can also look at `retracemem`, though I can't yet comment on its utility for setting the trace.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it would do it too. I didn't realize that you could use tracemem() this way.

Comment: That's a safer solution, but you would probably want to `untracemem` after your comparison, else you'll be notified every time any of the "traced" objects are altered.

Comment: Safer, but you won't be a wizaRd, just a muggle.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when looking for a function that checks whether a single variable is referenced *at all*, especially in the context of [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another?rq=1). Extending the other answers, I believe the following function does this:

```r
is_referenced <- function(x) {
  nom <- as.character(substitute(x))
  ls_ <- ls(parent.frame())
  ls_ <- ls_[ls_ != nom]
  tr <- tracemem(x)
  for (i in ls_) {
    if (identical(x, get(i, envir = parent.frame()))) {
      if (identical(tr, tracemem(get(i, envir = parent.frame())))) {
        untracemem(x)
        untracemem(get(i, envir = parent.frame()))
        print(i)
        return(TRUE)
      } else {
        untracemem(get(i, envir = parent.frame()))
      }
    }
  }
  untracemem(x)
  FALSE
} 

x <- 1:10
y <- x
is_referenced(x)
#> [1] "y"
#> [1] TRUE

z <- 1:10
is_referenced(z)
#> [1] FALSE

y[1] <- 1L
is_referenced(y)
#> [1] FALSE


library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = 1)
ET <- DT
is_referenced(DT)
#> [1] "ET"
#> [1] TRUE
is_referenced(ET)
#> [1] "DT"
#> [1] TRUE

ET[, y := 1]
is_referenced(DT)
#> [1] "ET"
#> [1] TRUE

DT <- copy(ET)
is_referenced(DT)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2018-08-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>