# Reference for R wizards

Tags: r, internals

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326865/in-r-how-can-i-check-if-two-variable-names-reference-the-same-underlying-object/7327426#7327426), I learned of a special class of internal functions that can be accessed from R: a set of functions accessed via `.Internal(specialFunction)`.  If one queries `?.Internal` this excerpt may be found:

> Only true R wizards should even consider using this function, and only R developers can add to the list of internal functions.

I want to master <strike>potions and defense against the Dark Arts for my OWLs</strike> interesting R functions.  Where can R wizards find a list and description of the internal functions?  <strike>So long as it doesn't involve splitting my soul.</strike>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're in [`src/main/names.c`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/names.c) but they are not alone.  The `.Primitive` are there too.  And some dragons.

They are documented in [Section 2) .Internal vs .Primitive](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) in the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - where's the documentation?  Double, double toil and tRouble...

Comment: @Iterator: sorry, I got focused on the "list" and missed the "description" in your question.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info.  However, there's something quite odd.  I looked in the R Internals (seems like a good place to find .Internal :)), but I gave up because I didn't find `inspect`, from your answer.  In other words, there's another secret guide that includes `inspect`, or else this is undocumented.  The plot thickens.  I have turned up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick/3396245#3396245) note left by...you.  :)

Comment: @Iterator: _R Internals_ doesn't discuss `inspect`.  The section I linked to only discusses `.Internal` and `.Primitive`.  I added a link to `names.c`, which lists all the `.Internal` and `.Primitive` functions.  I learned about `inspect` when it was mentioned on the R-devel mailing list.  When it comes to the internal R code, "the code *is* the documentation". ;-)

Comment: Fine, I'll take your word for it, but that's splitting my soul.  Again.  :)  (I searched the web, SO, John Chambers' recent book, Amazon, Google books...  if this is documented somewhere, someone's made that documentation invisible.  Darn "true" wizards.)