# Using Next in a Control Flow

Tags: r

There doesn't seem to be any examples of 'next' usage in the [control flow help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Control.html). I'd like it to skip to the next iteration based on a condition within the script.

Using the example below, let's say I don't want it to print, unless `x[i] > 5`, the expected output would be 5 through 10 on screen:

```
x <- 1:100
for(i in 1:10) {
# next(x[i] < 5) # Just for conceptualizing my question.
print(x[i])
}
```

How would I go about implementing the use of `next` to accomplish something like what's shown above?

Comment: It would be nice if SO had a [tag:missing-documentation] tag.  For all those little things where the R manual is incomplete.  :)

Comment: @Iterator: the documentation isn't _missing_ (`?"next"`), so maybe a "documentation-missing-example" tag?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Errm, I added a link to the documentation for this case.  However, [as you know](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7327565/805808) there are other cases where the documentation is ... left as an exercise.  :)  However, there is a "code-example" (and "code-examples") tag.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich the problem was that there's not really a clear way to see an example of usage of `next` from the documentation. `example(next)` is similarly useless.

Comment: Hmm, this makes me think of cases where I have a dataset, but elements are `NA`.  Is my dataset half full or half empty? Same with documentation. Anyway, maybe the "code-examples" tag is better here.  I still think there's a lot of undocumented functionality in R.  :)

Comment: @Iterator: That's what I meant to say. It _is_ documented but an example would really help because `next` and `break` aren't functions with arguments. I would also like if `?continue` took you to `?"next"`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  Maybe in the next iteration...  :)

Comment: I know it's V-day, but that was cheesy.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Cheesy? You should meet my friend "multithreader" and his jokes.  ;-)  "OS: You've got nice threads." "Process: Wanna spawn?" "OS: Go fork yourself."

Comment: @Iterator 7 years later, I just giggled at this horrible joke...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will give you a complete example and a 'yes' but I am unsure what your questions is:

```
R> for (i in 1:10) {
+     if (i < 5) next
+     print(i)
+ }
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
R>
```

Answer (score 10):

To make this work, you need to test whether `x < 5` and, if it is, go to `next`.  `next` will, in turn (to quote the help page), "[halt] the processing of the current iteration and [advance] the looping index", starting back through the loop again.

```
x <- 1:100
for(i in 1:10) {
    if(x[i] < 5) next
    print(x[i])
}
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```