# Is there an R function for duplicating a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to duplicate my data frame and store it for later use.  Can anyone please help me with the function?

I tried the `rm` function and the `copy` function but it  is not working

`df1 <- copy(df)`

The function `copy` is not working.

Comment: `df1 <- df` should do it.

Comment: `copy()` is from `data.table` package, try `data.table::copy(.)`.

Comment: Look [How do I create a copy of a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983118/how-do-i-create-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-r/51143421) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make new variable `df1` and give it the value of `df`:

```
df1 <- df
```