# In R, how can I check if two variables reference the same R6 object?

Tags: r, r6

The [identical()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/identical.html) function seems to give the correct answer, but the documentation doesn't explicitly discuss object references.  The closest note in the documentation is:

> Checking equality for two large, complicated objects can take longer
>   if the objects are identical or nearly so, but represent completely
>   independent copies.

Some examples of using identical():

```
QuickClass <- R6::R6Class("QuickClass",
  public = list(
   initialize = function(x) {
     private$px <- x
   }
   ),
   active = list(
     x = function(px) {
       if(missing(px)) return(private$px)
       else private$px <- px 
     }
   ),
   private = list(
     px = 0 
   )
)

> a <- QuickClass$new(1)
> identical(a, a)
[1] TRUE
> b <- a
> identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE
> c <- QuickClass$new(2)
> identical(a, c)
[1] FALSE
> d <- QuickClass$new(1)
> identical(a, d)
[1] FALSE
```

So, identical looks to do what is needed, I just want to check if there is a better way e.g. a specific function that just compares object references so may be faster and more directly applicable.  identical() looks like it can resort to field-by-field comparisons.

*Contrast clause:  This question is similar to [In R, how can I check if two variable names reference the same underlying object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326865/in-r-how-can-i-check-if-two-variable-names-reference-the-same-underlying-object/7327426#7327426) - however that question is quite old (pre-R6 classes) and the answers discuss using low-level techniques that I would rather avoid.*

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a random `id` for each new object and compare the `id`s.

```
library(R6)

MyClass <- R6Class(
  "MyClass",
  public = list(
    id = NULL,
    initialize = function(){
      self$id <- as.character(sample(1:10^6, 1))
    }
  )
)

MyClass$equal <- function(object1, object2){
  object1$id == object2$id
}

A <- MyClass$new()
B <- MyClass$new()
MyClass$equal(A, A)
# TRUE
MyClass$equal(A, B)
# FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible approach however I was wondering if there was a built-in/R6 function that say does a more basic comparison (like comparing memory locations).  Also, using a random number could I suppose lead to collisions when sample() returns the same number for two different instances.  But the idea of using a property could work e.g. if the id number was ever-increasing.

Comment: I agree that this approach has some downsides. Guaranteeing unique ids is certeinly possible by using a counter instead of an RNG. `all.equal.environment` is also a possible choice altough it compares instances on an objet level rather than an reference level (so memory locations are irrelevant)